# unable to install pip on windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am a new python user and am trying to install pip by using "python get-pip.py install" in the command prompt but end up with this error message:

"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions:)
No matching distribution found for install"

I have Python 2.7 and Windows 10. Image link below shows error message and web link shows code that I copied into the get-pip.py file. Is there some other install for pip for a different version...?

[image of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaLmu.png)

https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: Did you try these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136000/cannot-install-pip-on-windows-10 ? Did they work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer notes the issue may be due to your path. However i would reccomend just using chocolatey:
https://chocolatey.org/

This is a package manager that handles a lot of things for you. Once you install chocolatey (very simple installation). You can go ahead and type `choco install pip` in a command window. This should handle the installation of pip for you. It can also be used for many other things, i.e. anaconda, python itself, and much more.

Comment: I use windows 10 and choco install pip gives `ERROR: The term 'easy_install' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,..` and `ERROR: Python is not installed. easy_install installation aborted!`. Maybe `python.exe` has to be in the `path`. `py.exe` is in path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing this problem because you haven't added python to Path Environment Variable. 
You do that and things will be smooth.

As far as this problem is concerned

Open command prompt in the folder where you have downloaded 'get-pip.py.' file (shift + right click)
then run 'python get-pip.py'