# why "pip install" doesn't work but "python -m pip install" works?

Tags: python, path, pip, windows-10

I've recently reinstalled windows on my workstation so I needed to reinstall python and pip, before the reinstallation, the command `pip install whatever` was working properly.
But then after the reinstallation of Windows 10 when I type that command it won't return anything, not even an error, I've searched other solution and I found that this command `python -m pip install whatever` works fine.

What is changed?

How can I let the first command work again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install PIP on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136000/cannot-install-pip-on-windows-10)

Comment: You should update your `PATH` so it should know where `pip.exe` is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a PATH problem. On a standard Python3 installation on Windows, `python.exe` and `pip.exe` are in different folders. Let us say that Python is installed just under TOP, then:

- `python.exe` (and `pythonw.exe`) are in `TOP\Python3x` (x being minor version such as Python37)
- `pip.exe` is in `TOP\Python3x\Scripts`
- `py.exe` is in WINDOWSDIR (normally `C:\Windows`)

That is the reason why:

- `py -m pip install ...` always works on Windows (provided pip is installed)
- `python -m pip install ...` requires `...\Python3x` to be in the PATH
- `pip install ...` requires `...\Python3x\Scripts` to be in the PATH

Answer (score 1):

pip is a python script, and because you have not added to path variable the link to the "Scripts" folder;
this "Scripts" folder is situated on "C:location where python is installed\Scripts";

ex. for me : "C:\Python36\Scripts"; so i type on cmd prompt to set the path variable:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python36\Scripts
```

you can see the link: [https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm]

Answer (score 1):

As Bensalem has said, you need to add pip to your variable path in order to be able to use it without calling the script with `python` (which *is* in your path).

The `-m` refers to the passable argument to `python`;

> -m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

Answer (score 0):

you should add `pip` to ur environment variable(`path` windows), try [this](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation)